# match repeated character in sed on mac

Tags: bash, sed, bsd

I am trying to find all instances of 3 or more new lines and replace them with only 2 new lines (imagine a file with wayyy too much white space). I am using sed, but OK with an answer using awk or the like if that's easier.

**note**: I'm on a mac, so sed is slightly different than on linux (BSD vs GNU)

My actual goal is new lines, but I can't get it to work at all so for simplicity I'm trying to match 3 or more repetitions of `bla` and replace that with `BLA`.

Make an example file called stupid.txt:

```
$ cat stupid.txt

blablabla
$
```

My understanding is that you match *i or more things* using regex syntax `thing{i,}`.
I have tried variations of this to match the 3 `bla`s with no luck:

```
cat stupid.txt | sed 's/bla{3,}/BLA/g'      # simplest way
cat stupid.txt | sed 's/bla\{3,\}/BLA/g'    # escape curly brackets
cat stupid.txt | sed -E 's/bla{3,}/BLA/g'   # use extended regular expressions
cat stupid.txt | sed -E 's/bla\{3,\}/BLA/g' # use -E and escape brackets
```

Now I am out of ideas for what else to try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If slurping the whole file is acceptable:

```
perl -0777pe 's/(\n){3,}/\n\n/g' newlines.txt
```

Where you should replace `\n` with whatever newline sequence is appropriate.

`-0777` tells perl to not break each line into its own record, which allows a regex that works across lines to function.

If you are satisfied with the result, `-i` causes perl to replace the file in-place rather than output to stdout:

```
perl -i -0777pe 's/(\n){3,}/\n\n/g' newlines.txt
```

You can also do as so: `-i~` to create a backup file with the given suffix (`~` in this case).

If slurping the whole file is not acceptable:

```
perl -ne 'if (/^$/) {$i++}else{$i=0}print if $i<3' newlines.txt
```

This prints any line that is not the third (or higher) consecutive empty line.  `-i` works with this the same.

ps--MacOS comes with perl installed.

Comment: I am not sure what "slurping" means outside the context of a delicious noodle bowl... but it worked! To replace many empty lines with only 2, I substituted as you suggested: `perl -0777pe 's/(\n){3,}/\n\n\n/g'`

Comment: :-) `slurp` actually means *"to suck up the entire file in one go into memory"*, rather like noodles. It can be a great technique, like here, but is sometimes not the best approach with massive files where a *"stream-based"* approach is preferable, like `sed` the **stream** editor.

Answer (score 6):

`thing{3,}` matches `thinggg`. Use `(..)` to group things to make the quantifier apply to what you want:

```
$ echo blablabla | sed -E 's/(bla){3}/BLA/g'
BLA
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -E 's/bla{3,}/BLA/g'
```

The above matches `bl` followed by three or more repetitions of `a`.  This is not what you want.  It appears that you actually want three or more repetitions of `bla`.  If that is the case, then replace:

```
$ sed -E 's/bla{3,}/BLA/g' stupid.txt
blablabla
```

With:

```
$ sed -E 's/(bla){3,}/BLA/g' stupid.txt
BLA
```

The above, though, doesn't directly help with your task of replacing newlines because, by default, `sed` reads in only one line at a time.

#### Replacing newlines

Let's consider this file which has 3 newlines between the `1` and `2`:

```
$ cat file.txt

1



3
```

To replace any occurrence of three or more newlines with a single newline:

```
$ sed -E 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/\n{3,}/\n/g' file.txt

1
3
```

How it works:

- `H;1h;$!d;x`

  This complex series of commands reads in the whole file.  It is probably
  simplest to think of this as an idiom.  If you really want to know
  the gory details:

  - `H` - Append current line to hold space
  - `1h`  - If this is the first line, overwrite the hold space
    with it
  - `$!d` - If this is not the last line, delete pattern space
    and jump to the next line.
  - `x`  - Exchange hold and pattern space to put whole file in
    pattern space
- `s/\n{3,}/\n/g`

  This replaces all sequences of three or more newlines with a single newline.

#### Alternate

The above solution reads in the whole file at once.  For large (gigabyte) files that could be a disadvantage.  This alternate approach avoids that:

```
$ sed -E '/^$/{:a; N; /\n$/ba; s/\n{3,}([^\n]*)/\1/}' file.txt # GNU only

1
3
```

How it works:

- `/^$/{...}`

  This selects blank lines.  For blank lines and only blank lines, the commands in braces are executed and they are:
- `:a`

  This defines a label `a`.
- `N`

  This reads in the next line from the file into the pattern space, separated from the previous by a newline.
- `/\n$/ba`

  If the last line read in is empty, branch (jump) to label `a`.
- `s/\n{3,}([^\n]*)/\1/`

  If we didn't branch, then this substitution is performed which removes the excess newlines.

**BSD Version**:  I don't have a BSD system to test this on but I am guessing:

```
sed -E -e '/^$/{:a' -e N -e '/\n$/ba' -e 's/\n{3,}([^\n]*)/\1/}' file.txt
```

Comment: Instead of all those sed commands in case of new lines, someone can use just `sed -z` as soon as input file has not null chars inside.

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou That is very true for anyone on Linux or otherwise using GNU sed.  The OP, though, said he was on a Mac.

Comment: When I ran your first suggestion, the new lines were properly identified but oddly they were replaced with an "n" instead of an actual new line. so the output from your example was `1n3`. This seems strange since it was able to properly interpret the first `\n`.

Comment: I also tried the second "BSD Version" suggestions, but I got this error: `sed: 1: "s/\n{3,}([^\n]*)/\1/}` `": bad flag in substitute command: '}'` so maybe there is some kind of typo. However, when I generate a bigger file it'll likely be on a linux server, so the GNU example is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

To keep only 2 newlines, you can try this sed

```
sed '
  /^$/!b
  N
  /../b
  h
  :A
  y/\n/@/
  /^@$/!bB
  s/@//
  $bB
  N
  bA
  :B
  s/^@//
  /./ {
    x
    G
    b
  }
  g
' infile
```

---

/^$/!b    If it's a empty line don't print it

N         get a new line

/../b     if this new line is not empty print the 2 lines

h         keep the 2 empty lines in the hold buffer

:A        label A

At this point there is always 2 lines in the pattern buffer and the first is empty

y/\n/@/   substitute \n by @ (you can choose another char not present in your file)

/^@$/!bB  If the second line is not empty jump to B

s/@//  remove the @

$bB  If it's the last line jump to B

At this point there is 1 empty line in the pattern space

N  get the last line

bA  jump to A

:B label B

s/^@//  remove the @ at the start of the line

/./ {   If the last line is not empty

x  exchange pattern and hold buffer

G  add the hold buffer to the pattern space

b  jump to end

}

g  replace the pattern space (empty) by the hold space

print the pattern space

Comment: This mostly worked, but for some reason the final line of text is removed. I made a slightly longer example file than in the original question that consisted of multiple lines of text separated by variable numbers of new lines. And it worked, except that the final line of text was removed also.

Comment: @rrr update answer to keep the last line if it's not empty.