# Trying to find and replace with sed using back-references, output is not desired result

Tags: regex, sed

I'd trying to use sed to replace double commas with single commas preceeding dates in my file. Desired behavior is as follows:

Input: `,,2020-01-01`

Output: `,2020-01-01`

My code: `sed 's/,\(,[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}\)/\1/g' stuff.csv > stuff2.csv`

However the output file appears unchanged. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why not simply `s/,,*/,/g`?

Comment: `sed` out of the box does not support `{2}`; maybe try `\{2\}` or see if your `sed` supports either of the nonstandard options `-E` or `-r`.

Comment: I don't want to replace all double commas, just those preceeding dates. Thank you for your comment, escpaing the brackets did the trick!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50124142/match-repeated-character-in-sed-on-mac asks about Mac, but has several answers which are actually Linux only; unfortunately, none of the answers there actually explain the problem. I'll see if I can find a better duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{` is part of the [extended regular expression](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html#REGULAR_EXPRESSIONS) syntax and thus should be escaped:

```
sed 's/,\(,[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\)/\1/g' stuff.csv > stuff2.csv
```

Alternatively, if you are using GNU sed, you can use the `-r` option and get rid off the escaping:

```
sed -r 's/,(,[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})/\1/g' stuff.csv > stuff2.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your regex doesn't work is that you tried to use the ERE regex feature `{2}` which is not supported by standard `sed`.

If your `sed` supports POSIX BRE regex syntax, try

```sh
sed 's/,\(,[0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\}\)/\1/g' stuff.csv > stuff2.csv
```

i.e. backslash the curlies just like how you are already backslashing the round parentheses.

Some `sed` versions support ERE regex syntax with `-E` or `-r` but this is not portable. If it works in your `sed`, you should not have backslashes before the round parentheses, either.

The plethora of regex dialects and the variability in support for them among different `sed` implementations is a huge wart; sometimes the easiest way to produce working and portable code is to switch to a different tool. Ironically, Perl is not standard at all (and has completely its own regex dialect, though it is now by and large *de facto* standard in most modern regex tools) but it's installed most everywhere, and has remained stable and backwards-compatible with itself for a long time.

For the record, BRE is the POSIX standard for *Basic Regular Expression* syntax (roughly what the original `grep` supported) and ERE is *Extended Regular Expression* syntax, based on what was originally introduced in `egrep` (which is now POSIXly called `grep -E`).